# Yii2 UploadedFile::getInstance() returns null

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

When my form is sent `UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'images')` returns `null`. I also tried `UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('images')`. In the `$_POST` array the `images` key is empty e.g. `'images' => ['']`. The file exists in `$_FILES` array.

My code is pretty simple. My view:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'validation-wizard wizard-circle floating-labels',
        'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'
    ],
]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'images[]')->fileInput([
    'id' => 'image_0',
    'class' => 'dropify',
    'data-default-file' => ''
]) ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

In my model I have:

```
public $images;
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['images', 'each', 'rule' => ['file']],
    ];
}
```

Comment: Why you're using `images[]` as a field name instead of `images`?

Comment: Because I need more than 1 image. But also tried whit `images` without brackets for single image. The result was the same.

Comment: Then you should use `getInstances()` instead of `getInstance()`.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you a lot. You can post your answer below so to let me approve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to access an array of files, you need to use [`UploadedFile::getInstances()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile#getInstances()-detail) instead of `UploadedFile::getInstance()`.

```
$files = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'images');
```

Good example of handling multiple files can be found in guide in [Uploading Multiple Files](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-file-upload#uploading-multiple-files) section.

Comment: if sending file from another form except YII2, like sending file from mobile application, set file parameter name to UploadForm[<your_file_field_name>] to work with UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'images'), else $file would be empty.